# Unable to retrieve the object from S3 by Codebuild project with cross-account ECR source action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I am creating a pipeline that uses ECR Source Action, CodeBuild Action and ECS Deploy Action. The ECR Source is in another AWS account, say Account E. The pipeline and Codebuild is in, say Account P. The pipeline has been successfully created and it is also triggered when new image with tag "latest" is pushed to the ECR. The sourceArtefact is created in an S3 bucket in Account P. The KMS keys are shared cross account and everything is working fine until this stage.

When the Codebuild Action is trying to fetch the sourceArtefact in the Download Source phase, it is seen with the following error

> CLIENT_ERROR: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403, request id: XXXX, host id: XXXX for primary source and source version arn:aws:s3:::XXX-pipeline-artefact-bucket/mypipeline/Artifact_e/vA9hDcq

The Artifact Bucket in Account P has the following bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<ACC-P>:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<ACC-P>:role/CodeBuildRoleXXXXX"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-pipeline-artefact-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-pipeline-artefact-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACC-E>:role/XXXecrsourceactionrole406755410defee62c0ca"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:Abort*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-pipeline-artefact-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXX-pipeline-artefact-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have a CodePipeline Role and Codebuild Role that contains the AWS S3 full access policy in it. They also have access to the KMS key.

I can remove the codebuild action and directly have ECS Deploy action but I am sure it is going to face the same issue. However, the reason to have CodeBuild Action is to construct the imageDetail.json to have the application version as tag instead of "latest" so that we don't deploy new version accidentally when new task is created in ECS.

How do I fix this Access Denied issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try allowing cross accounts access to the s3 bucket.Resources which might be useful:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3

Comment: Thanks @Hiranya. This one helped me. All I had to add was the Object Ownership for the bucket with `BUCKET_OWNER_ENFORCED` when I craete the Artifact Bucket.